# Round Android Wear Emulator is Square

Tags: android, interface, emulation, rounding, wear-os

The title and picture say it all--my round android wear emulator shows the rect layout.  I'd appreciate any tips that help me get the round emulator to show the correct interface.

Created AVD using instructions from:
[Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html)

Android Studio 0.8.1 Beta, SDK Tools 23.0.2, Wear target is 4.4W(API 20)

[image]
[image]

**Creating the AVD using Wayne's Command Line method created an AVD that shows the correct UI**

Comment: Interesting, mine comes out round; except with the Eclipse IDE (missed that part about Android Studio, but it shouldn't matter since they both use the same tool I would suspect).

Comment: This appears to be fixed in the new `5.0.1` x86 system image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure when you create you AVD that you select the following options for a round emulator:

Device: Android Wear Round (320 x 320: hdpi)
Target: Android 4.4W - API Level 20
CPU/ABI: Android Wear ARM (armeabi-v7a)
Skin: AndroidWearRound

Alternatively, you can create round or square emulators with the command lines:

```
android create avd --force -n WatchRound --target "android-20" --device "Android Wear Round" --skin AndroidWearRound --abi android-wear/armeabi-v7a
android create avd --force -n WatchSquare --target "android-20" --device "Android Wear Square" --skin AndroidWearSquare --abi android-wear/armeabi-v7a
```

It is important that Device and Skin are both consistent, and you cannot mix round and square with the same emulator. If the problem still happens, post a screen shot of your configuration.

Comment: My AVD was created with the above recommended settings (and I made a new one to test it out just to be sure--it had the same issue).  Added screenshot of my AVD Settings to my OP.

Comment: Creating the AVD from Command Line like you suggested fixed it--thanks Wayne!

Comment: Command line is the way to go. The GUI must be broken, as the same options do not result in the same outcome.

Comment: same problem, and resolved with staring emulator from command line

Comment: As mentioned in another answer: The key is to not enable "Use host CPU". This makes the screen square. It's also no problem to create a Round Android Wear AVD with a intel x86 CPU.

Comment: I have seen other reports that enabling the GPU can cause problems here, so my command lines above did not enable the GPU, hence why it worked. I upvoted the other answer about turning off the host GPU support.

Comment: Followed these instructions but the AVD won't let me launch the device.  Instead of the play button I just see "Repair Device".  Clicking on this displays nothing.

Answer (score 23):

You don't have to use the command line to create the AVD. You should just make sure you turn off "USE HOST GPU" as this feature currently doesn't support the round watch face.

Comment: Once switch off Host CPU, the simulator seems to hung.

Answer (score 2):

I'd second Wayne's suggestion to use the command line to create the AVDs.  If you just disable "Use Host GPU" from the UI, you get the round skin, but the wearable layouts are all still made for square displays, so the content is cut off in the corners. Also, using

```
android create avd --force -n WatchRound --target "android-20" --device "Android Wear Round" --skin AndroidWearRound --abi android-wear/x86
```

to create an x86 based emulator runs quite a bit faster on PCs in my experience.