# Android Wear automatic layout

Tags: android-studio, wear-os

This is my first try with Android Studio, i have used Eclipse for my previous applications.
I am create an application for Google Wear and i want to include the function to automatic change the layout depending on square or round watch.

And this is actually the default code but i cant get it to work, maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

It always uses the square layout, i have tried it on actual round watch (Moto 360) and also in the layout windows in Android Studio and even if i pick the Wear Round option it still uses the square layout.

Activity.java

```
private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_wear_activity);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    });
}
```

rect_main_wear_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainWearActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear_square">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_square" />
</LinearLayout>
```

round_main_wear_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainWearActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear_round">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_round" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

main_wear_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_main_wear_activity"
app:roundLayout="@layout/round_main_wear_activity"
tools:context=".MainWearActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear">
</android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

Comment: I rebooted the Moto 360 and now it works on that device, still same problem in Android Studio, maybe its not possible to test this function there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the AndroidWear Round emulator this was clearly a bug. Today Google released the **SDK Tools 23.0.4** as well as a new **ARM EABI v7a** system image (rev2) which should fix the bug you've described in your post.

Here's the "official" statement by *[Wayne Piekarski](https://plus.google.com/114844270757025925192/posts/HeScPcG4fVb)*:

> The Android Developer Tools team has just released SDK Tools 23.0.4.
>   This version contains an update for the AndroidWearRound emulator, so
>   that there is now one correct profile instead of the three different
>   profiles that existed before. So go to the Android SDK Manager and
>   download the update to SDK Tools 23.0.4, as well as Android Wear ARM
>   EABI v7a System Image rev. 2, and then recreate your AndroidWearRound
>   AVD in the AVD Manager.

I've just tested this and I can confirm that this bug is solved. However it's still not possible to use the Host GPU. (Problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640879/round-android-wear-emulator-is-square))